# Sending email from a query on previous php page

Tags: php, mysql, email

Forgive me but I think I went in too deep for my skill level:
database connection is set in the include:

Here is the code:

```
<html>
  <body>
      <?php
      include "inc.php";
      //print_r ($_POST);


      //if "email" is filled out, send email
      if (isset($_POST['email']))

      {
          //send email
          While($row=mysql_fetch_array($querymail))
          {
              $to= $row['email'];
              $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'] ;
              $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
              $email= 'stats@my email.com';
              mail($to, $subject,
              $message, "From:" . $email);
              echo "email sent to ".$to;
          }
      }
      else
      //if "email" is not filled out, display the form
      {

          $Pnum=implode(',',$_POST['checkemail']);
          $querymail=mysql_query("select sp.email_address as email from stats_player sp where sp.player_num IN ($Pnum)");
          While($row=mysql_fetch_array($querymail))
          {
              echo "<table>";
              echo "<tr><td>".$row['email']."</tr.</td>";
          } 
          echo "<form method='post' action=''>

          Subject: <input name='subject' type='text'><br>
          Message:<br>
          <textarea name='message' rows='15' cols='40'>
          </textarea><br>
          <input type='submit'>
          </form>";
      }
  ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

when i allow the `print_r ($_POST);` I get all of the player_nums displayed as expected.

The page opens with a list of email properly (this table will go away it is only there to verify the data)
and I get the form .

When I hit the Submit button on the form though, I get errors.

```
Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in /home..../results/admin/emailall.php on line 31

Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home..../results/admin/emailall.php on line 33
```

I think since I have this form re-submitting to itself it is clearing what I had in the initial query. I thought I had bypassed that with the isset but I could (probably am) wrong.

**(note I removed some empty lines when pasting so error lines will not correspond)**

Comment: You don't show how/where you actually DO the database query, e.g. where $querymail is actually created.

Comment: You are trying to implode $_POST['checkemail'], but obviously this isnt an array ($_POST['checkemail'][]). At least its impossible for us to see the full image as you havent posted your actual form.

Comment: @MarcB '//if "email" is not filled out, display the form
      {

          $Pnum=implode(',',$_POST['checkemail']);
          $querymail=mysql_query("select sp.email_address as email from stats_player sp where sp.player_num IN ($Pnum)");
`

Comment: @Tom when the page first loads is creates a table of email names based upon the implode and that works fine. The form simply consist of a Subject text field and a message text field. The error occurs After the submit button is pressed.

Comment: can you please post the `print_r` output? maybe using pastebin or gist

Comment: @Maluchi The `print_r` at the beginning is simply a list of numbers (which is expected). The numbers pop into the implode function as is then plug into the query. The query then spits out a bunch of email addresses. Up to that point it works. Where it all fails is when I enter in the email form and press the submit. it doesn't take the query results and loop through sending mail

Comment: in that case, can you please share the output of `var_dump($_POST['checkemail'])`?, it seems that variable isn't a collection (array, object)

Comment: @Maluchi I added this at teh beginning `include "inc.php"; print 'Post info<br>'; print_r ($_POST); print '<br>Vardump info<br>'; print var_dump($POST['checkemail']); print '<br>end Vardump<br>'; //if "email" is filled out, send email if (isset($_POST['email']))` the output is as follows when teh page is entered:`Post info Array ( [Email_Submit] => Email [checkemail] => Array ( [0] => 62 [1] => 3 ) ) Vardump info NULL end Vardump` The table that I generate is `emailforuser3@gmail.com emailforuser62@gmail.com` The "emailforuserXX is the actual email name for that user.

Comment: @Maluchi The emailofuserXX is actually the user's email, just changed for this posting. Below the table I have a text input for Subject: and a text input for Message: followed by a submit button. When Submit is pressed I get `Post info Array ( [subject] => testing [message] => Disregard this ) Vardump info NULL end Vardump Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in /home/esda/www...sults/admin/emailall.php on line 34 Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/esda/www...sults/admin/emailall.php on line 36`

Comment: @Maluchi it would appear that list of emails and/or the list of usernames does not get passed. I am thinking I might be best to start a session on the previous page and just pass that session info to this page and a new following page?

Comment: yes, when you submit, you need to handle the variable in the POST using the form... maybe you can use a hidden input field in your form to pass the array with the submit button

Comment: @Maluchi I will have to look into how to do that. As for the coding, does it appear I am going down the correct road?